# Excel Wild Card With Dates

Tags: excel, datetime, wildcard

I have a table of values with different date times. I'm attempting to create a new columns that sorts values that fall within a specific time range of 6:00am to 6:00pm. The physical calendar day does not matter, so I'm attempting to use wildcard but I keep coming up with a False result for values that should be true.

[image]

Here's what I have.

```
=IF(AND(A2>="*"&"06:00 AM",A2<"*"&"18:00 PM"),B2,"0")
```

Comment: Is your TimeStamp data actual DateTimes, of just strings that look like DateTimes?  If it's strings, then convert it to actual DateTimes and use Scott's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(A2,1)>=TIME(6,0,0),MOD(A2,1)<TIME(18,0,0)),B2,0)
```

[image]

Comment: That is not very descriptive, what are you getting?

Comment: As you can see from my edit it works for me.

Comment: Apologies. I fat fingered it. Thanks a lot